# Django Rest Swagger 2 not parsing Serializer FieldField correctly

Tags: python, json, django, swagger, swagger-ui

Let us say I have the following serializer:

```
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     file = serializers.FileField(max_length=100)
```

My view looks like this:

```
class FileUploadView(generics.CreateGenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.FileUploadSerializer
    parser_classes = (parsers.FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        # do something here
```

I expected the swagger UI to generate a file upload button that you can click to choose a file from the file system. Instead, I was asked to input a JSON data:

[image]

In the older version of the Django Swagger, I can just specify the parameter type as `file` in the YAML docstrings. However, I am using Django Swagger 2+ where YAML docstrings are no longer supported.